# Why can't I read and extract this HTTP header while performing a GET XmlHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript

Basically I'm trying to extract a HTTP header from a GET request using JavaScript.

Not sure why I'm unable to extract the 'Server:' HTTP header?

I have the following JavaScript:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('GET', document.location, false);
req.send(null);
var headers = req.getAllResponseHeaders().toLowerCase();
console.log(headers);
console.log("Headers read successfully!");
console.log("extracting the Server header...");

//extract Server Header - I'm thinking the issue lies within this function... particularly how the values are split?
function readHeaders(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + ":";
    var ca = headers.split(' ');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

var extract = readHeaders('server');
console.log(extract)
```

The output for variable `extract` should be something like `Apache` (or whatever server is in use).

Comment: Seems like you’re trying to read the response headers before the request comes back. What does the `console.log(headers)` call output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to parse the header, what you have described can be done with [getResponseHeader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/getResponseHeader).

Meanwhile, both `getAllResponseHeaders` and `getResponseHeader` are not available until the `HEADERS_RECEIVED` event so you will have to put it in the `readystatechange` event handler like this.

```
req.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if(this.readyState == this.HEADERS_RECEIVED) {
    // The search for the header name is case-insensitive
    var result = req.getResponseHeader("Server");
  }
}
```